# Ignoring some text from ascii file

Tags: python, merge, save

Thank you for the time you´ll spend reading it.
 I have this kind of data (I´ll show only just a few lines bacuse it is almos 3000 lines)

### evento_T_A.ascii

```
2015-04-15T07:00:52.260000  15842
2015-04-15T07:00:52.270000  10292
2015-04-15T07:00:52.280000  10845
2015-04-15T07:00:52.290000  13727
2015-04-15T07:00:52.300000  13496
2015-04-15T07:00:52.310000  11406
2015-04-15T07:00:52.320000  9494
2015-04-15T07:00:52.330000  11018
2015-04-15T07:00:52.340000  11873
2015-04-15T07:00:52.350000  10749
2015-04-15T07:00:52.360000  11761
2015-04-15T07:00:52.370000  12352
2015-04-15T07:00:52.380000  11365
2015-04-15T07:00:52.390000  13574
```

---

I did some programing (not the pythonic way) to ignore 2015-04-15T all this words and just trying to keep

07:00:52.260000  15842 
07:00:52.270000  10292
...
07:00:52.390000  13574

here it is my code

```
ff=open('evento_T_A.ascii','r')
tiem=[]
for line in ff:
     line=line.strip()
     columns=line.split()
     Tiempo=columns[0]
     Amplitud=columns[1]
     Tiemp=str(Tiempo)
     if "T" in Tiemp:
          tiem=Tiemp[11:]
          print (repr(tiem))
     else:
          print "None"
ff.close()
outo=open('XY.txt','w')
for line in tiem:
    outo.writelines(repr(tiem))
outo.close()
```

but when I open the XY.txt I just get the last value not all the raw of data.
when I did the step `print (repr(tiem))` I could see all the data but when I did `outo.writelines(repr(tiem))` it just saved one line.

my first doubt:
- How can I merge Tiempo and Amplitud to look like this:

```
07:00:52.260000  15842 
07:00:52.280000  10845
07:00:52.360000  11761
...
07:00:52.390000  13574
```

- how can write all the data in just one txt?

Thank you a lot for the time you spent reading it-

Tonino

Comment: First, why do you try to write the `repr` of each item, instead of the item itself? The `repr` of each string is going to be something like `'07:00:52.260000\n'`—with the quotes, backslash escapes, etc. I can't imagine you want that.

Comment: Next, `writelines` takes a list (or other iterable) of all of your lines. Don't use it inside a `for` loop; you're saying that for each line, write all the lines. Ouch. Either you want `outo.writelines(tiem)` or `outo.writelines(line + '\n' for line in tiem)` or similar, or you want `for line in tiem: outo.write(line)` or `for line in tiem: outo.write(line + '\n')` or similar.

Comment: Thanks Abarnet, you were rigth, but it still saves only the lat value not all the values I mean, i t just saves 07:00:52.390000  not all 3000 times of values, do you have any idea?, thank in advance

Comment: Yes. The thing is, you have multiple problems, and just fixing one problem without fixing the others won't help, so it's hard to know where to start. I've tried to write an answer that puts it all together.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem isn't how you write the list out; it's that you don't build the list in the first place.

You start off well, with an empty list:

```
tiem=[]
```

But then, instead of appending lines to it one by one, you just keep replacing it with the values from each latest line:

```
tiem=Tiemp[11:]
```

If you want to append lines to a list, you use the `append` method:

```
tiem.append(Tiemp[11:])
```

Now `tiem` is the list of every 11th column, instead of just the last 11th column.

---

Your next problem *is* how you write the list out:

```
for line in tiem:
    outo.writelines(repr(tiem))
```

With your existing code, `tiem` is a single string (representing the last time), so `for line in tiem` is looping over the characters of that time. And then, for each character, you ignore that character and write out `repr(tiem)`, which is the string representation of that whole string. So, you write `'13574'`, then `'13574'` again, then `'13574'`, `'13574'`, and `'13574`'.

After the first fix, this gets even worse. Now, for each line in the list of lines, you're printing the repr of all of the lines. So, you're going to print something like `['15842', '10845', '11761', blah blah, '13574']` 3000 times in a row.

The big problem is that you're calling `writelines` with the whole list, once for each element. Just do one or the other. Either:

```
outo.writelines(tiem) # note no for loop
```

… or …

```
for line in tiem:
    outo.write(line) # note, line, not tiem
```

Notice that I also got rid of the `repr`. That's where the extra quotes, brackets, maybe some backslashes, etc. came from. You're explicitly asking for not the string itself, but the Python literal that would create that string. You don't want that, don't do it.

---

The next problem is that you haven't put any newlines in anywhere. But that's easy:

```
for line in tiem:
    outo.write(line + '\n')
```

---

Finally, how do you extend this to put two columns together?

You could build two lists, `tiem` for the times and `amp` for the amplitudes, then `zip` them together.

Putting it all together:

```
ff=open('evento_T_A.ascii','r')
tiem, amp = [], []
for line in ff:
     line=line.strip()
     columns=line.split()
     Tiempo=columns[0]
     Amplitud=columns[1]
     Tiemp=str(Tiempo)
     if "T" in Tiemp:
          tiem.append(Tiemp[11:])
          amp.append(Amplitud)
          print Tiemp[11:]
     else:
          print "None"
ff.close()
outo=open('XY.txt','w')
for t, a in zip(tiem, amp):
    outo.write('{} {}\n'.format(t, a))
outo.close()
```

Comment: Dear Abarnet, thank you a lot for the you spent it, the code works fines and so many thank for clarifying the use of writelines, so well now I will attached all the code, I hope it can help someone else, all my best regards!!!, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're just trying to keep everything to the right of the "T", and that "T" won't appear anywhere else in the line, why don't you just use `split()`? A minimal example with your data here:

```
l = ['2015-04-15T07:00:52.260000  15842\n',
'2015-04-15T07:00:52.270000  10292\n',
'2015-04-15T07:00:52.280000  10845\n',
'2015-04-15T07:00:52.290000  13727\n']

tiem = []
for line in l:
    tiem.append(line.split('T')[1])

out = open('out.txt', 'w')
for line in tiem:
    out.write(line)

out.close()
```

The output in out.txt will look like:

```
07:00:52.260000  15842
07:00:52.270000  10292
07:00:52.280000  10845
07:00:52.290000  13727
```

Better yet, if you don't need to do anything with that data,

```
l = ['2015-04-15T07:00:52.260000  15842\n',
'2015-04-15T07:00:52.270000  10292\n',
'2015-04-15T07:00:52.280000  10845\n',
'2015-04-15T07:00:52.290000  13727\n']

out = open('out.txt', 'w')
for line in l:
    data = line.split('T')[1]
    out.write(data)
out.close()
```

will produce the same output.

Comment: Dear Pencil, thanks a lot for the time you spent on it, also the code works, many thank, I will upload all the code for someone else maybe it will help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the code thank you a lot Abernet and Pencil, and of course thanks to Obspy.

Script to convert from Seisan waveform to Ascii 2 columns 
Called saveASCII_xy.py         (byG0d&+0n1n0_A_P) 
Many thanks to Abernet and Pencil 'cause they contributed to done it.
saveASCII_xy.py

```
from obspy import read
import os
import csv
import string
import numpy as np

patho=raw_input('Path to Go-->')
os.chdir(patho)
listaa=[f for f in os.listdir(patho)]
print listaa
no_ar=raw_input('Data Name-->')
data_in=read(no_ar)
data_in.write('salida.ascii',format='TSPAIR')
data_inn=open('salida.ascii')
data_out=open('evento_T_A.ascii','w')
for i in range(1): 
    data_inn.next()
    for line in data_inn: 
            data_out.writelines(line)
data_inn.close()
data_out.close()

ff=open('evento_T_A.ascii','r')
tiem=[]
amp=[]
for line in ff:
        line=line.strip()
        columns=line.split()
        Tiempo=columns[0]
        Amplitud=columns[1]
        Tiemp=str(Tiempo)
        if "T" in Tiemp:
                tiem.append(Tiemp[11:])
                amp.append(Amplitud)
#                print Tiemp[11:]
        #else:
        #       print "None"
ff.close()
outo=open('ASCII_XY.txt','w')
for t, a in zip(tiem,amp):
        outo.write('{} {}\n'.format(t, a))
outo.close()
```

If it is not so pythonic way so sorry, I am learning, any suggest and comment will be so nice about the code to tonino.gafm@gmail.com

Thank you a lot!!!